# How to use Telegram's TDlib with Node.js

Tags: node.js, telegram, tdlib

There is TDlib which allows to work with Telegram Client API.

[Documentation says](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/) that it's possible to use it with almost any language.

I can't imagine myself how I can use it with Node.js

Could you tell me where to start from or provide me with a sample code?

Comment: https://github.com/k-egor-smirnov/node-tg-native

Comment: @dereli seems that I had to google more. Thank you!

Comment: I will add an answer for the sake of the question being replied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably port one of the examples on their [GitHub repos](https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example) (Python can be an easy one). You needs to learn how to use binary modules with node.

Or you can check one of the 3rd party libraries (eg. https://github.com/k-egor-smirnov/node-tg-native)

Answer (score 5):

You can make requests and get updates using [td_json_client](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/td__json__client_8h.html) and [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) interfaces. Official repository provides a simple [example](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/javascript/example.js).

If you don't want to create API client from zero, you may use one of exists. For example, check out [Airgram](https://github.com/airgram/airgram). This is a strong typed `tdlib` client for NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 active TDLib wrappers in Node.js:

- https://github.com/airgram/airgram
- https://github.com/Bannerets/tdl

Both require you to build the TDLib binary yourself before using these wrapper: https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html